# Laravel race condition dynamic database connections problem

Tags: php, laravel, database, dynamic

i think i will have a problem with race condition because of dynamic database.

My API in each request will connect to a different database, multiple clients will use it, but each client has his own data base (SQL SERVER).

I'm changing the connection in the constructor of the controller:

On construct:
DB::disconnect(env("DB_CONNECTION"));

```
    Config::set('database.connections.' . env("DB_CONNECTION"), array(
        'driver'    => $data->driver,
        'host'      => $data->servername,
        'database'  => $data->database,
        'username'  => $data->user,
        'password'  => $data->password,
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ));
```

On destruct:

```
    DB::disconnect(env("DB_CONNECTION"));
```

With this, the rest of the controller, can work normal with the ORM.

My question is, if i have about 200 requests on each client, how are the chances, of a wrong connection?

Because the config is global, if another request comes in, before the last is finished, what will happen?

I'm thinking to change the connetion in the model, it will be focused there, and not long before, like de controller. But I dont know if will be enough. PHP only suports one connection at time rigth? So it is not even a laravel problem.

I'm using:

- Laravel 9
- PHP 8
- SQL SERVER

Thank you all for your time, have a great day.

Comment: Errata: PHP can have multiple connections, but using laravel config set, in this case only one.

Comment: And i will have too many connections to use config array of connections.

Comment: each PHP request is independent and sandboxed unless you're using something like [octane](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/octane) so there's no spillover of data from one request to another